# if statement checking value of multiple check boxes

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make an if statement that requires more than one of three checkboxes to be selected, however I get a syntax error with the code that I have.

```
var proceed = true;
        if($("#chek1:checked, #checked2:checked, #checked3:checked').length ==1")){
    alert("error");
    proceed = false;
}
```

Comment: Can you add your `HTML` also

Comment: Just noticed the extra ' after checked3:checked, that seems to have fixed it.

Comment: @user2168066 Please before posting question on SO, open your console :)

Comment: I did, i have looked through it multiple times. A programmer missing one quote seems fairly common.

Answer (score 0):

use **[filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**

```
 $("#chek1,#checked2,#checked3").filter(":checked").length
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/090w362f/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var proceed = true;
if($("#chek1:checked, #checked2:checked, #checked3:checked").length == 1)
{
    alert("error");
    proceed = false;
}
```

Or if your checkboxes have the same name value, like name="myChecked[]", you can do something like this:

```
count_checked = $('[name="myChecked[]"]:checked').length

if(count_checked == 0)
{
   doSmt();
}
```